# android default download manager

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I want to use android's default download manager.

I mean I have a url. I just invoke android's default download manager by giving the url. Then the rest (stop, pause, delete download ques) is with download manager.

I tried to manipulate downloads by myself but it seems android's default download manager is better and easier.

Comment: there is nothing like download manager, the one you are talking about is a part of browser

Comment: @IftikarUrrhmanKhan: incorrect, there is a DownloadManager

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are welcome to [use `DownloadManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html) on API Level 9 and above, which delegates the download to the built-in Downloads app.